# Find any N-character substring match

Tags: string, excel, substring, vba

I have Excel worksheets with many rows containing unknown strings of arbitrary length and content. For example:

```
str1 = "AKMDHVIIDMEHGOKDJNFJD"
str2 = "DJRWFNCGNDKDJHBC"
```

Given minimum substring length N, how can I determine if any N-length or longer substring from `str1` exists anywhere in `str2`?

I could do it by brute force with something like:

```
For N = 4 To Len(str2)
    For pos = 1 To Len(str2) - N
        subStr = Mid(str1, pos, N)
        If InStr(str2, subStr) > 0 Then
            'Do stuff
        End If
    Next pos
Next N
```

But this comparison needs to run thousands of times. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be considered more important to achieve a longer substring's existence first? If some substring 6 chars long is found then 5 and 4 char length substrings are also going to be found. i.e. Shouldn't your loops run from long to short?

Comment: @Jeeped You are certainly correct. The code in the question was thrown together as a quick example of what I *can* do, but would rather not have to resort to. Hence I didn't spend too much effort making it perfect. That said, I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. If a substring with char length 4 is found, you should continue to look for lengths of 5, 6, etc. If not found, kick out with an Exit For on the inner loop 'cause if length 4 not found then lengths of 5, 6, etc will never be found.

Comment: Please read about Longest common subsequence problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-subsequence/

Comment: @Jeeped To minimise checks, you probably also want to make Position the outer loop, and Length the inner loop...  Start at position 1 of the shortest string, and increase string length until we don't find a match in the longer string, and move on to position 2, etc.